# SQL Aggregate function issues

Tags: aggregate, distinct

I have a table that has the following data:

```
id  status  date    part_no part_name 

1   high    1/2/09  55      screw;
1   medium  1/2/09  55      screw; 
2   high    2/2/09  32      plug;
3   low     4/8/09  59      bolt;
4   medium  5/6/09  48      tie;
4   low     5/6/09  48      tie;
```

I want to write a query that will give me one row per id number and I want to be able to show all the fields in the result.  for instance the result of my query should be:

```
1   medium  1/2/09  55  screw;
2   high    2/2/09  32  plug;
3   low     4/8/09  59  bolt;
4   low     5/6/09  48  tie;
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: One DISTINCT row per Id or are you trying to SUM/AVG/MIN/MAX?

Comment: if you were to get the results table you asked for you would be disregarding some of your columns: namely, date & part_no

Comment: I want one distinct row per id.

Comment: @jen: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id,
    MIN(status),
    MIN(date_part),
    part_name
FROM <table>
GROUP BY
    id,
    part_name
```

Comment: can you do a min() on the status column with varchar values like low, medium, and high?

Comment: I was looking at this from the perspective of the questioner.  If order is important, other means would be necessary (@OMG Ponies started that thread)

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT id, 
          MIN(status), 
          date, 
          part_no, 
          part_name  
    FROM table
GROUP BY id, date, part_no, part_name
```

..is what you're going for, but the complication is that you're storing strings so it depends on the db for how it applies the MIN function to text/characters.  In a normalized setup, the status would be a separate code table, and the key would/could be an ID which would work better with the MIN function.

Comment: This database is anything but normalized and allows the user to input information that is inconsistent with the business rules. The user is allowed to downgrade a status in the same day so using max(date) worked for records that have different dates but did not work for records that have the same date